What is the reason for gaining 2 reputation points on accepting someone else's answer?
This question has been bothering my mind for quite some days now. When a user accepts an answer to their question, they gain 2 reputation points unless it is a self-answer. What is the reason for this? Is it to encourage users to accept the most helpful answer once their query has been resolved?

The reason is to encourage users to accept answers. It benefits the answerers, as they receive 15 rep for the time spent to help answer a question, and also benefits visitors of the question, so they can see confirmation of a solution that did resolve the issue.
More information is available in the FAQ question on accepting answers.
